# Two counters on different threads counting until one is done

Tags: java, multithreading, locking, counter, counting

Make 2 thread counters - counting from start to end value. The value of the counter should be displayed for each count. One thread is set to count to a smaller value than the other. When one of the threads counts to the setpoint, the other stops and completes its execution.
This is my task so I made a solution with a AtomicBoolean run = new AtomicBoolean(true);

```
/**
 * Implements {@link Runnable} and his method {@link Runnable#run} to run until stop is set to true
 * and count is less than maxCount.
 */
public class Counter implements Runnable {
    private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(Counter.class);
    private static final String MAX_COUNT_EXCEPTION_MESSAGE = "maxCount should be bigger than zero!";
    private static final int NUMBER_TO_CHECK_MAX_COUNT_VALIDATION = 1;
    private AtomicBoolean run;
    private int count;
    private int maxCount;

    /**
     * Constructs a counter with zero count and run equal to true with a specified maxCount.
     *
     * @param maxCount of the counter
     * @throws IllegalArgumentException if maxCount is smaller than 1
     */
    Counter(int maxCount, AtomicBoolean run) {
        if (maxCount < NUMBER_TO_CHECK_MAX_COUNT_VALIDATION) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException(MAX_COUNT_EXCEPTION_MESSAGE);
        }
        this.maxCount = maxCount;
        this.run = run;
    }

    /**
     * Entry point.
     * <p>
     * Runs until run is set to false and count is less than maxCount.
     * <p>
     * On every loop {@link Counter} increment count with 1 and print the count.
     */
    @Override
    public void run() {
        while (count < maxCount && run.get()) {
            incrementCount();
            logger.info(this + " : " + count);
        }
        run.set(false);
    }

    /**
     * Used for obtaining current value for the count.
     *
     * @return count.
     */
    int getCount() {
        return count;
    }

    /**
     * Increment the count.
     */
    private void incrementCount() {
        count++;
    }
}

/**
 * Runs two counters and print the counting for both of them until one reach his maxCount then both are stopped.
 */
public class RunnerTwoCounters {
    private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(RunnerTwoCounters.class);

    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
        AtomicBoolean run = new AtomicBoolean(true);
        Counter counter1 = new Counter(2, run);
        Thread thread1 = new Thread(counter1);
        Counter counter2 = new Counter(10, run);
        Thread thread2 = new Thread(counter2);
        thread1.start();
        thread2.start();
        thread1.join();
        thread2.join();

        logger.info(counter1 + " " + counter1.getCount());
        logger.info(counter2 + " " + counter2.getCount());
    }
}
```

How can I make the same thing to work but without Atomicboolean just to work with Object lock and some synchronization on it?

Answer (score 0):

This does what your recent comment says. Both threads start counting.  When one reaches the setPoint, they both stop.

```
public class ThreadCounting {

    int value1;
    int value2;
    volatile boolean flag = true;
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new ThreadCounting().start();
    }

    public void start() {
        int setPoint = 100;
        Thread begin = new Thread(() -> {

            while(flag && ((value1 = counter1()) <= setPoint)) {
                System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName() + "     counter1 = " + value1);         
            }
            flag = false;
        });

        Thread finish = new Thread(() -> {

            while(flag && ((value2 = counter2()) <= setPoint)) {
                System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName() +" counter2 = " + value2);
            }
            flag = false;

        });

        begin.start();
        finish.start();

    }
    int val1 = 1;
    public int counter1() {
        return val1++;
    }
    int val2 = 1;
    public int counter2() {
        return val2++;
    }
}
```

Comment: When I execute the main method into the RunnerTwoCounters the output into the console is:

Comment: [Thread-0] INFO com.sirma.javacourse.threads.twocounters.Counter - com.sirma.javacourse.threads.twocounters.Counter@66bec7ce : 1
[Thread-0] INFO com.sirma.javacourse.threads.twocounters.Counter - com.sirma.javacourse.threads.twocounters.Counter@66bec7ce : 2
[main] INFO com.sirma.javacourse.threads.twocounters.RunnerTwoCounters - com.sirma.javacourse.threads.twocounters.Counter@66bec7ce 2
[main] INFO com.sirma.javacourse.threads.twocounters.RunnerTwoCounters - com.sirma.javacourse.threads.twocounters.Counter@22d8cfe0 0

Comment: the two counters start counting on the two different threads and when the one reaches the setpoint, both of them stop counting

Comment: look at the code above to see into the main method what is going on and the above class Counter is used to make a two instances and to start two threads counting until the one counter reaches the max count for it for example if new Counter(5, Atomicboolean) this counter will count 0 1 2 3 4 5